# How to escape an invalid character (0x1F) in an XML file?

Tags: fme-form, xml

I want to convert an XML-file to something else. However, when I try to read it using the FeatureReader, it throws an error. I'm using FME Workbench 2021.2, and read the file without any special parameters. Here is a piece of the log file:

```
Creating reader for format: XML (Extensible Markup Language)
Trying to find a DYNAMIC plugin for reader named `XML'
Loaded module 'XML' from file 'A_Particular_Disk:\Apps\FME2021.2.4\plugins/XML.dll'
FME API version of module 'XML' matches current internal version (3.8 20210302)
...
XML Parser error: 'Error in input dataset: '\\Some\User\With\A\Data\Directory\large_file.xml' line: 9073245 column: 41 message: invalid character 0x1F'
```

There is an invalid character at some line in the file. It's a hexadecimal `0x1F` which I tried to replace using Python, but that did not work out. Since it's a rather large file, I cannot just manually remove the invalid character.

Is there any way to escape or replace an invalid character while reading an XML-file in FME?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's really a `0x1F` character in the XML file, it's indeed invalid, and you should ask whoever produced it to fix that.

Now, that may not always be possible or practical, so you might need to fix it yourself. I don't know about FME, but Python should definitely be able to do this.

I would do it in a generic way, like this: Read the XML file in blocks of, say, 1,000,000 bytes, and do a search for `0x1F`. If it's there, replace this single byte with (the byte representation of) `&#x1F;`: `0x26 0x23 0x78 0x31 0x46 0x3B`.

It might be possible to read the file line by line, which would make the search and replace a bit easier, because you can work with strings rather than bytes. But technically, the entire document could be on a single line which would require more memory. For this particular file, this does not seem to be the case though, it references line 9073245. If it's a one time thing, I'd probably use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your real task is to convert a non-XML file to an XML file.

In doing so, you have to decide what to do with the x1F character. What does it mean? Perhaps it's part of a chunk of binary data that needs to be preserved? In that case you'll have to convert the whole chunk to a representation that works in XML, such as base64 encoding. Or perhaps it's noise that can be discarded without problems, in which case your task is easier.

But in XML 1.0 there is no direct way of representing an x1F character that will work in an application-independent way, so you need to think about the problem end-to-end; what information is being conveyed and why is it miscoded in this way? Unless it's noise that can be discarded, you need to redesign the data flow in a way that will affect both the sender and the recipient.